# Using a directive with JS template itself

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying use a directive within the template itself.

However, the data never reaches my app. The field is just blank.

Can anyone assist?

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup, TranslationsService) {
     $ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(function () {
      if(true) { 

        $scope.translations = TranslationsService.getData();

         $ionicPopup.confirm({
             title: 'System warning',
             scope: $scope,
             template:   'MESSAGE HERE {{translations.logout}}'
         }).then(function(res){
             if( res ){
               navigator.app.exitApp();
             }
         })
      }
   })
})
```

Comment: Show `TranslationsService.getData` method. May be it is a promise call so before getting it resolved you are trying to show the template.

Comment: Yes I see- I tried to put `$scope.translations = TranslationsService.getData();` but it did not work. I think my order/syntax is wrong? I have updated my answer

Comment: Yes. `$scope.translations = TranslationsService.getData();` this line is the problem I think. You need to return promise. But show your service code for better understanding your problem.

Comment: Post definition of getData.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide confirm with scope object to compile template in. Also make sure you work with async `getData` properly:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup, TranslationsService) {
     $ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(function () {
      if (true) {

         $scope.translations = TranslationsService.getData();

         $ionicPopup.confirm({
             title: 'Exit?',
             scope: $scope,
             template:   'MESSAGE HERE {{translations.logout}}'
         }).then(function(res){
             if( res ){
               navigator.app.exitApp();
             }
         })
      }
   })
})
```

And in case if `getData` is async returning promise, then you need to do it like this:

```
TranslationsService.getData().then(function(data) {
    $scope.translations = data;
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but it has not worked.When I use your line `$scope.translations = TranslationsService.getData();` the PopUp does not even appear. Where to I put the last bit "in case getData is async"?

Comment: See edit- I've updated the OP to include my current code (I found where to put the TrasnalationsService.getData()

Comment: Make sure you add `scope: $scope` in modal configuration. And post `getData` code.

Comment: Still no success- this code stops the popup all together. I've updated the OP to include the code I'm currently using